# Implicit conversion to subclass not sufficient?

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I'm working with a library that has languages represented by objects of a certain type `Language` whereas in my code I'm using an enum `LanguageEnum` from another library that I can't change. I'm trying to build an implicit conversion from the enum to the `Lanuage` class anyway.

My idea: Create a subclass of `Lanuage` -- let's say `SubLanguage` and add and implicit conversion from the language enum to this class.

Although I can do that, it doesn't solve my problem. When i use my `LanugageEnum` where a `Language` is expected, the compiler complains that there is no conversion although the compiler can convert to a `SubLanguage` which should actually be sufficient.

The code looks like this:

```
public void DoSomethingWith(Language lang) {
}

// somewhere else I call it like this
DoSomethingWith(LanguageEnum.German);
```

Is it possible to solve my problem without using explicit conversions?

Comment: are you trying to convert collection of `SubLanguage` objects to  collection of `Language` objects ? Provide a line where conversion happens.

Comment: Why can't you implement another implicit conversion for Language that just calls the conversion to SubLanguage and then returns the returned SubLanguage object casted to Language?

Comment: You can't expect the compiler to search for every possible subclass of `Language` to see if it happens to define a conversion. You have to define a conversion from `LanguageEnum` to `Language` directly.

Comment: I updated the question. @A.Chiesa, I can't change the Language class. At least not in a way that makes it know either the enum or the subclass.

Comment: Create a factory class then that knows about the enum and can produce `Language` objects: `DoSomethingWith(LanguageFactory.Create(LanguageEnum.German));`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen well, I don't need a factory. Having the implicit conversion on the `SubLanguage` I can even just cast. But I'd like to get rid of the cast, too: `DoSomethingWith((SubLanguage) LanguageEnum.German)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an implicit conversion, you need to specify it exactly in the target type, not its subtypes - otherwise the compiler simply won't consider it.

See the relevant section from the C# specification, *6.4.4 User-defined implicit conversions*:

> A user-defined implicit conversion from type S to type T is processed as follows:
>
> - Determine the types S0 and T0. If S or T are nullable types, S0 and T0 are their underlying types, otherwise S0 and T0 are equal to S and T respectively.
> - Find the set of types, D, from which user-defined conversion operators will be considered. This set consists of S0 (if S0 is a class or struct), the base classes of S0 (if S0 is a class), and T0 (if T0 is a class or struct).

Thus, if you are assigning to a variable or field or parameter of type `Language`, a conversion needs to be declared there, not in `SubLanguage`.

But, if I may say so, don't fixate on implicit conversions. In the long run, there's nothing wrong with making operations explicit and visible. Especially if they are hugely representation-changing operations.